# Using recordmydesktop to create partial files of the recording

Tags: recording, screen-recorder

I need to use recordmydesktop to record a six days conference. Every day there is a 3 hour seminar that I need to record.
I need 2 things:

1. automatically start and finish the recording (using command line tools would be ok, that important thing is that I can specify the area to record)
2. **create every 15 minutes a partial file**. Basically I do not want to have at the end a 20GB file. I want to create 15minutes files.

n.2 is the most important feature I need. I will consider as correct answer the suggestion of an alternative (even on Windows platform) as long as it could satisfy both my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried GTK-Recordmydesktop? Is a front end for it.

With it (probably also with command line version) you can select an area of the screen to capture, very easily. (tutorial [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24742/record-screen-activity-in-ubuntu-with-recordmydesktop/)) (you can do the same by commandline, specifying offset and width/height parameters. A bit more tedious, though)

On the file size issue. You can lower the quality slider in the GTK gui. (there's a command line parameter for this), mark "encode on the fly", and unmark zero compression. And do a small test to find the lower quality you can use. FPS, frames per second captured, also vary the file size, but it can end up in a "jumpy" motion... Another option is just record it all, then use [these tools](http://en.flossmanuals.net/TheoraCookbook/ManipulateOggTheoraFiles) for splitting the file.

Obviously I guess just pausing the file and then restarting is not an option...

BTW, the software actually saves temp files, I think in chunks of 500mb, calling them img.out or something like that. With a recent "repair" function you can recover crashed session chunks. Might be this be a way to somehow re-create the chunks...An starting point, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem in my case it's not the final size but the time needed to create a file of a six hours recording. I was thinking that cutting in 15minutes part would do the trick to spare time but if it stores 500mb chunks maybe it's not necessary. I should do some test.